# Detect HTML datalist scroll

Tags: html, jquery, scroll, infinite-scroll

I'm using jQuery to populate `datalist` options via server, which works fine.

```
function loadInitialFunds() {
    $.ajax({
        url: myURL ,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        error: function (e) {
            console.error('Error retrieving funds', e);
        },
        success: function (funds) {
            $.each(funds, function(index, fund) {
                $("#codes").append($("<option>").attr('value', fund.code).text(fund.name));
            });
        }
    });
}

<input list="codes" type="text" name="code" id="funds" placeholder="Enter Code">
<datalist id="codes"></datalist>
```

I want to be able to detect the `scroll` event on `datalist` in order to query additional server results, simulating an infinite scroll functionality.

```
$( "#codes" ).scroll(function() {
  console.log('scrolling') // doesn't work
});
```

It seems that I'm unable to detect scroll events on such elements. How can I sort this out?